# Laravel fopen with write permission refresh page automatically

Tags: php, laravel

I am building a .env file which written using fopen(). However, once it is opened. The page just automatically refresh. If I change into "r" permission, it is not refreshed.

```
protected function createCredential(
        String $countryCode,
        String $countryLang,
        String $websiteName,
        WebsiteServer $websiteServer,
        Website $website,
    ) : String {
        $from = base_path().'/.env.example';
        $to = base_path().'/.env.bak';
        $fpFrom = fopen($from,'r');
        if (filesize($from) > 0) {
            $content = fread($fpFrom, filesize($from));
        }
        fclose($fpFrom);

        $fpTo = fopen($to,'w');
        dd('test');
        // Replace
        $toReplace = [
            'FILL_COUNTRY_CODE' => $countryCode,
            'FILL_LANGUAGE_CODE' => $countryLang,
            'FILL_APP_NAME' => $websiteName,
            'FILL_APP_URL' => 'https://'.$website->domain,
            'FILL_DB_DATABASE' => $websiteServer->server_user.'_'.$websiteName,
            'FILL_DB_USERNAME' => $websiteServer.'_user',
            'FILL_DB_PASSWORD' => 'JH5fgW&kXH',
            'FILL_MAIL_HOST' => 'mail.'.$website->domain,
            'FILL_MAIL_USERNAME' => 'support@'.$website->domain,
            'FILL_MAIL_PASSWORD' => '@bobby123@',
            'FILL_MAIL_FROM_NAME' => $websiteName,
            'FILL_MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS' => 'support@'.$website->domain,
        ];

        foreach($toReplace as $key=>$value){
            $content = str_replace($key,$value,$content);
        }

        fwrite($fpTo,$content);
        fclose($fpTo);
        return $to;
    }
```

There I use dd() to check where is the problem and find out it comes from fopen($to,'w'). I have no idea why it is happening.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because of no filename in the target destination.

```
 $to = base_path().'/.env.bak';
```

I changed into

```
 $to = base_path().'/temp.env.bak';
```

Now, it works without any errors. Hopefully this can help others